# git rebase --continue command not getting work

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

*Hi Everyone i trying to rebase local branch from origin master*

**steps**

```
 git pull origin master
 git checkout driver_management
 git rebase master
 git add .
 git rebase --continue
```

**while exicute git rebase --continue cmd getting this msg**

```
added new fields in driver model #67

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# interactive rebase in progress; onto 62effa7
# Last commands done (3 commands done):
#    pick 9e6cbf8 added urls for token authonetication  web api #67
#    pick e472943 added new fields in driver model #67
# Next command to do (1 remaining command):
#    pick d6dcca9 fixed driver form new field added
# You are currently rebasing branch 'driver_management' on '62effa7'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       modified:   fleet/forms.py
#       new file:   fleet/migrations/0091_auto_20220107_1046.py
#       modified:   fleet/models.py
#       modified:   fleet/templates/hiringprocess/driver_allocationform.html
#       modified:   fleet/templates/hiringprocess/edit_drivers.html
#       modified:   fleet/views.py
#
~
~
E:/10dec_everestfleet/everest_jarvis/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG [unix] (15:08 14/01/2022)
```

i don't know what will do next, i am stuck there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window whose text you pasted in your question is just a manual pause asking for a commit message, before making the commit and continuing the rebase.  If you are OK with the commit message already in the editor, simply do <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>:wq</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  If you want to edit that commit message first, then do <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, make the edit, then use the above command to save and close the window.